# vb.net HTTPWebRequest Header

Tags: vb.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, digest

I am using VB.net and I am trying to load a file using HTTPWebRequest.

I have found that if I am requesting a file that requires a username and password I need to set that in the header of the request like this:

```
Digest username=admin,password=21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3,realm=MyServer,nonce="3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c70079babf",uri="/data.xml",cnonce="3690046e5d2f641e5c4a8bd3dcf1f541",nc=00000003,algorithm=MD5,response="8f6129b934467074b3d0b9c543f7e025",qop="auth",opaque="4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74"
```

Howerver I found that that if the username or password or even the realm, nonce, cnonce,  response, opaque is wrong then it will deny access as well.

However when this happens and it denys access I need a way to read the header of the denyed header so I can read realm, nonce amd cnonce from it.

When I try and catch the error I am not sure what to use.

Is there a way to view the denyed header?

My Code I am using looks like this:

(it works but if the username or password etc. is incorrect it fails and I need to view the header of the failed request)

```
' Create a WebRequest to the remote site
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.30/data.xml")

' NB! Use the following line ONLY if the website is protected
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")

request.UseDefaultCredentials = False

request.Accept = "*/*"
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"

request.Headers("Accept-Encoding") = "gzip, deflate"
request.Headers("Pragma") = "no-cache"

request.ContentLength = 0
request.Method = "POST"

request.ContentType = "text/xml"
request.PreAuthenticate = True

Dim authorization_type As String = "Digest"
Dim username As String = "admin"
Dim password As String = "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3"
Dim realm As String = "MyServer"

Dim nonce As String = "3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c70079babf"
Dim Uri As String = "/data.xml"
Dim cnonce As String = "3690046e5d2f641e5c4a8bd3dcf1f541"
Dim nc As String = "00000003"
Dim algorithm As String = "MD5"
Dim response As String = "8f6129b934467074b3d0b9c543f7e025"
Dim qop As String = "auth"
Dim opaque As String = "4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74"


Dim Authorization As String = authorization_type & " username=" & username & ",password=" & password & ",realm=" & realm & ",nonce=""" & nonce & """,uri=""" & Uri & """,cnonce=""" & cnonce & """,nc=" & nc & ",algorithm=" & algorithm & ",response=""" & response & """,qop=""" & qop & """,opaque=""" & opaque & """"

request.Headers("Authorization") = Authorization.ToString

' Call the remote site, and parse the data in a response object
Dim response1 As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

' Check if the response is OK (status code 200)
If response1.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then

    ' Parse the contents from the response to a stream object
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response1.GetResponseStream()
    ' Create a reader for the stream object
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
    ' Read from the stream object using the reader, put the contents in a string
    Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Create a new, empty XML document
    Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

    ' Load the contents into the XML document
    'document.LoadXml(contents)

    MsgBox(contents) ' used for testing

    ' Now you have a XmlDocument object that contains the XML from the remote site, you can
    ' use the objects and methods in the System.Xml namespace to read the document

Else
    ' If the call to the remote site fails, you'll have to handle this. There can be many reasons, ie. the 
    ' remote site does not respond (code 404) or your username and password were incorrect (code 401)
    '
    ' See the codes in the System.Net.HttpStatusCode enumerator 

    Throw New Exception("Could not retrieve document from the URL, response code: " & response1.StatusCode)

End If
```

Comment: why are you explicitly showing your password? keep it secure